# Getting Syntax Error on : `driver.findElement(By.css("//*[@id='search Input']")).sendKeys("Este");`

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please anyone reply for this error, I am getting **syntax error** on this line and also I have tried with different element locators
please find the script below.

```
public class wikipgm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\www.wikipedia.org");
    }
    driver.findElement(By.css("//*[@id='search Input']")).sendKeys("Este");
}
```

Comment: `By.cssSelector("//*[id='search Input']")` or `By.xpath("//*[@id='search Input']")` is the correct way

Comment: @KishanPatel, `"//*[id='search Input']"` is not valid `CSS` selector. I guess you mean `"*[id='search Input']"`

Comment: Yes @Andersson. Typo

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to locate element `By.css` (If you use `Java` then correct method is `By.cssSelector()`) using actually `XPath` expression instead of `CSS` selector

Try to select appropriate from

```
By.cssSelector("#search Input")
By.xpath("//*[@id='search Input']")
```

Check [this](https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/05/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/) to get more info about how else you can locate webelements

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.css("//*[@id='search Input']")).sendKeys("Este");

Write above in **Main method**.
Its not getting executed.Good Luck

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\www.wikipedia.org");
   driver.findElement(By.css("//*[@id='search Input']")).sendKeys("Este");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :
driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("Este");